# React js not displaying '<a href...' as a link

Tags: css, reactjs, href

```
Click on <a href='https://test.com' target="_blank">https://test.com</a>
        2. Select data
            2.1 Filter by Database Name
            2.5 Click Save
        3. Select DB
            3.1 Check Primary
```

I'am sending the above string data coming from database to react and it is getting displayed inside the 'pre' tag.But the href link inside the string is not showing as a link.it is showing the complete text as it is..
how to show link inside pre tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please consider using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute in react.

```
function createMarkup() {
return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

for more info visit :https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Also consider XSS attacks when you want show raw data from database.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

If you only pass a normal string to React render function, it is by default treated as a normal string because of XSS vulnerability, which is also why a separate prop is created specifically to inject innerHTML to remind developer that injecting HTML is dangerous.

Here's a working example:

```js
class Pre extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return React.createElement(
      'pre',
      {
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {
          __html: `Click on <a href='https://test.com' target="_blank">https://test.com</a>
        2. Select data
            2.1 Filter by Database Name
            2.5 Click Save
        3. Select DB
            3.1 Check Primary`
        }
      },
      null
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Pre, null, null),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```